# Render multiple overlapping polygons using a single SKShapeNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I discovered that it's possible to render multiple polygons using a single SKShapeNode object:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let polygons = [
            [
                CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100),
                CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)
            ],
            [
                CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50),
                CGPoint(x: 50, y: 150),
                CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150),
                CGPoint(x: 150, y: 50),
            ],
        ]

        let path = CGMutablePath()

        for points in polygons {
            path.addLines(between: points)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }

        let node = SKShapeNode(path: path)
        node.fillColor = UIColor.red

        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

However, any space where polygons overlap is rendered as empty:

[image]

Is it possible to fill those empty spaces, while continuing to use a single node?

Comment: The short answer is...you can't. However, you can create an image from the polygons, create a texture from the image, and create a sprite node from the texture.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @0x141E I tried the texture generation approach, but it was too slow to do it on each frame, which is what I need for a shape-shifting node.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a kluge  workaround if you don't care about the border.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let polygons = [
            [
                CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100),
                CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)
            ],
            [
                CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50),
                CGPoint(x: 50, y: 150),
                CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150),
                CGPoint(x: 150, y: 50),

            ]
        ]

        let path = CGMutablePath()

        for points in polygons {
            path.addLines(between: points)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }

        let first = CGMutablePath()
        first.addLines(between: polygons[0]);
        first.closeSubpath()

        let second = CGMutablePath()
        second.addLines(between: polygons[1]);
        second.closeSubpath()

        let node = SKShapeNode(path: first)
        node.fillColor = .red
        node.strokeColor = .red

        let child = SKShapeNode(path: second)
        child.fillColor = .red
        child.strokeColor = .red
        node.addChild(child)


        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

If you care about the border, then ...

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let polygons = [
            [
                CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100),
                CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)
            ],
            [
                CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50),
                CGPoint(x: 50, y: 150),
                CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150),
                CGPoint(x: 150, y: 50),

            ]
        ]

        let path = CGMutablePath()

        for points in polygons {
            path.addLines(between: points)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }

        let first = CGMutablePath()
        first.addLines(between: polygons[0]);
        first.closeSubpath()

        let second = CGMutablePath()
        second.addLines(between: polygons[1]);
        second.closeSubpath()

        let node = SKShapeNode(path: first)
        node.fillColor = .red
        node.strokeColor = .white
        node.lineWidth = 2

        let child = SKShapeNode(path: second)
        child.fillColor = .red
        child.strokeColor = .white
        node.lineWidth = 2
        node.addChild(child)

        let child2 = SKShapeNode(path: first)
        child2.fillColor = .red
        child2.strokeColor = .clear
        node.lineWidth = 2
        node.addChild(child2)


        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

Comment: Erm... this doesn't satisfy the main constraint - it uses multiple SKShapeNode objects.

Comment: It appears that the blend mode used internally for merging multiple polygons within a single shape node is "subtract", so the overlapping area has no color. This is the best workaround I could find. At least this way, we can manipulate the composite shape as a single entity.